# Decompose time series using R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm new to R.

What I'm trying to do is to decompose a time series, which is given in hourly resolution.

My data looks like this:

```
Time    traffic
6/7/2005 7:00   56718587433
6/7/2005 8:00   76456162968
6/7/2005 9:00   82534038485
6/7/2005 10:00  88796995092

 ...

7/28/2005 10:00 51528036132
7/28/2005 11:00 69610584123
7/28/2005 12:00 76364975533
7/28/2005 13:00 81281257078
```

In order to decompose my data to trend, seasonal and stationary components, this is what I tried:

```
library(xts)
library(forecast)
data<-read.csv("my_file.csv")
data<-ts(data[,2],frequency = 24*365, start=c(2005,6,7,7))
decompose(data)
```

but this is the error I'm getting:

```
Error in decompose(data): time series has no or less than 2 period
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `frequency = 24*365` you are signaling that you want the unit of time to be years. Since you have less than two months of data,  you do not have 2 periods (years).  Try using days as your basic unit instead - i.e. try `frequency = 24`

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean to set the frequency to 24, that will then forecast the hourly data. If you want to determine multiple effects, ie hourly, daily, weekly, monthly etc then you can explore the tbats() function in the forecast package which can detect multiple seasonalities, or you can also use a fourier model to extract the effects of different underlying periodicities.

Includes code relating to forecasting using fourier:

http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tbats-with-regressors/

Information on how you should set the frequency:

http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/